# Creating a Haskell selector function

Tags: haskell, types, synonym

I have the following two type definitions in Haskell which are from Thompsons 'Craft of Functional Programmingi', Second Edition, 1999.

```
type ShopItem = (String,Int)
type Basket   = [ShopItem]
```

When I try to create my own 'selector function' on these types as such:

```
name  :: ShopItem -> String
price :: ShopItem -> Int
```

GHCI gives me the following error.

```
The type signature for ‘name’ lacks an accompanying binding
```

Why isn't 'name' bound to the String element of the ShopItem tuple and likewise for 'price'?

Is this older syntax that is no longer acceptable in the current version of GHCI? I'm using version 7.10.3 on current Linux Mint 18.

Comment: GHCi is just telling you that you've only written down the signatures for two selector functions `name` and `price` but without writing the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the implementations of `name` and `price`:

```
name :: ShopItem -> String
name (n, _) = n

price :: ShopItem -> Int
price (_, p) = p
```

You could also use `data` instead of `type`, and use record notation:

```
data ShopItem = ShopItem { name :: String, price :: Int }
```

Then these can be used to extract fields:

```
item = ShopItem { name = "Beans", price = 2 }
-- or
item = ShopItem "Beans" 2

name item  ==  "Beans"
```

But also to replace them:

```
item { price = 4 }  ==  ShopItem { name = "Beans", price = 4 }
```

Comment: Many thanks Jon. Your solution is in Thompson's book, I just didn't understand what he was doing.

Comment: Great blog too, Jon

Comment: Jon, Do you have a favorite Haskell text?

Comment: @Ron: I’ve heard good things about this: http://haskellbook.com/ but I can’t really recommend anything firsthand—I mainly learned Haskell by using it for hobby projects, and later at my job.